# Aesthetic issues when booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, command-line, dell, laptop

Haven't been able to find anything on this with my masters degree in Google-Fu, so this should be a good question. Here we go:

When booting my laptop, and after the POST screen, Ubuntu will go back in forth between the command line, the Ubuntu "loading" screen (The word Ubuntu with dots underneath), and an NVidia screen.

Now the only thing that should be showing is the Ubuntu loading screen, no flashing screens or anything else (although the NVidia screen is completely normal operation due to using the proprietary driver). I've had this problem for years (since Ubuntu 10.04 I believe) and it's finally bothered me enough to do something about it.

So how would I go about fixing this? Sorry if I haven't included enough information as I have absolutely no idea where to start on this. Just tell me what info you need and I will supply!

The laptop model is a Dell Latitude E6530, although this has happened on about five other computers in the past years.

NOTE: To be clear, Ubuntu *does* boot and operate completely fine, this is just an aesthetic thing I suppose.

Comment: do you have a dual graphics card set up? sound like maybe the computer or plymouth can't decide which card to use. try a graphical splash --- solar looks pretty good

Comment: Technically, I do. My laptop uses Optimus to switch between integrated Intel HD Graphics, and my dedicated NVS 5200M card, but I have this disabled in BIOS so the dedicated graphics card is always in use, and never integrated (it's been my experience that Ubuntu doesn't play well with Optimus without a lot of tweaks I don't want to do).

Could this still be the issue though? And how would I go about using a "graphical splash"?

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia driver from the Ubuntu repos, or from one downloaded from the Nvidia web site?

Answer (score 0):

How is your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line configured (do a `cat /etc/default/grub` to view the output)?

You may want to consider adding the following kernel boot parameters:

- `quiet` = Don't show terminal output unless an error occurs
- `splash`= Show splash theme, if available
- `nomodeset` = Do not load video drivers until X is loaded

For the sake of testing, I'd recommend that you add these parameters one at a time and test (with a reboot) before proceeding. With the `nomodeset` parameter in particular, on some machines, it is known to generate a black screen after booting into the desktop.

**Note**: whenever you make changes to your `grub` file, you need to run `sudo update-grub` to generate a new grub cfg file in `/boot`.

Rich